# ¿Acceder a los elementos de una matriz bidimensional por columna?

Tags: java, array

Existe alguna manera de obtener las columnas de una matriz por columna en dos ciclos repetitivos, es decir si tengo la matriz:

```
A =

[21.0][16.0][16.0][13.0][11.0]
[17.0][18.0][14.0][23.0][13.0]
[32.0][27.0][15.0][41.0][19.0]
[6.0] [10.0][12.0][15.0][43.0]
```

El acceso a los elementos se hace a través de dos ciclos, uno para las filas y otro para las columnas, en código es:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("["+A[i][j]+"]");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

El acceso se hace por cada fila, pero si quisiera obtener algo como:

```
Columna 0
[21.0]
[17.0]
[32.0]
[6.0] 
Columna 1
[16.0]
[18.0]
[27.0]
[10.0]
.
.
.
Columna N
```

No he logrado hacerlo.

Alguien mencionaba que se puede hacer cambiando i por j al momento de acceder a los elementos, algo asi:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("["+A[j][i]+"]");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Sin embargo al hacer eso, lanza una excepción ya que j es mayor al total de filas por lo que el indice no se encuentra en la matriz.

**¿Como podría obtener el resultado esperado?**

Comment: Por lo que veo, la matriz que indica es de 1 dimensión, o al menos de 1 sola columna, de manera que deberías indicar el numero de columnas y calcular la posición con el típico casilla=columna*columnas+fila (empezando a contar por 0).
O mas fácil, que la matriz sea de 2 dimensiones y se soluciona con un simple bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu arreglo bidimensional es N x N, el código sería así:

```
double[][] A = ...
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(A[j][i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Asumiendo que tu arreglo bidimensional es N x M donde M es constante, el código sería así:

```
double[][] A = ...
for (int i = 0; i < A[0].length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(A[j][i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi solución al problema:

```
public class MatrizImprimirColumnas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[][] M = {
                { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6 },
                { 4, 6, 2, 5, 1, 3 }
        };

        imprimirMatrizPorColumnas(M);
    }

    private static void imprimirMatrizPorColumnas(int[][] m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m[0].length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Columna " + (i + 1));
            imprimirColumna(m, i);
        }

    }

    private static void imprimirColumna(int[][] m, int col) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("[" + m[i][col] + "]");
        }

    }
}
```

Esta es la salida del programa:

```
Columna 1
[1]
[1]
[4]
Columna 2
[2]
[3]
[6]
Columna 3
[3]
[2]
[2]
Columna 4
[4]
[5]
[5]
Columna 5
[5]
[4]
[1]
Columna 6
[6]
[6]
[3]
```